# passlib checksum doesn't verifies with SHA2 of MySQL

Tags: mysql, hash, sha256, passlib, mqtt-vernemq

I am using vernemq to authorize users from database using SHA256 algorithm. I observe that when creating new entry in table using buildin mqsql function `SHA2`,

```
INSERT INTO vmq_auth_acl 
    (mountpoint, client_id, username, 
     password, publish_acl, subscribe_acl)
SELECT 
    '', 'newUser2', 'newUser2', SHA2("CJJPL9", 256), 
     '[{"pattern":"botOut"}] ', 
     '[{"pattern":"botIn/#"}]';
```

which generates hash value something like this `54d0e30d0a00d86451a3353a2123fc1f006faaba6b55ef0d168390f26cbab82a` and Vernemq server successfully verifies this user when logged in using `CJJPL9` password.

But when I add this entry into this table from python code using passlib library `sha256_crypt.encrypt("CJJPL9")`, which generates hash as follows 
 `$5$rounds=80000$wnsT7Yr92oJoP28r$cKhJImk5mfuSKV9b3mumNzlbstFUplKtQXXMo4G6Ep5`. I know, due to salt, the hashs will be different, but there is a clear difference in the formatting of both hashes and as a result, verneMQ server fails to verify the credentials for this user. The [formatting](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.html#format-algorithm) of passlib library says that it keeps only 43 characters from 256-bit checksum. I also tried testing by only keeping the checksum part of the passlib hash string, but still no luck.

I want to know what is the difference between encryption of MySQL `SAH2("CJJPL9", 256)` and `sha256_crypt.encrypt("CJJPL9")`.

Comment: When I read "authorize users with SHA2" I read "login system with an alarmingly weak hash used". At the absolute least you need to use a password-specific hash like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) that's deliberately slow and difficult to brute-force. SHA2-256 is a high-speed hash that can be done at *terahashes per second* on specialized hardware. It's utterly useless for passwords, even at a large number of rounds.

Comment: You appear to be looking at hex encoding versus base-64 encoding.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for pointing that out. Yes I'd love to, but vernemq doesn't supports `Bcrypt` for mysql yet.

Comment: @user207421 you might be rite. Sorry m new to all this. I'll check if passlib supports base64 encoding. Meanwhile `hashlib` library seems to do the work.

Comment: Hi AnumSheraz, VerneMQ developer here. You're right bcrypt isn't supported yet with mysql - it's in the backlog, we just didn't get around to it yet. I think @user207421 is correct that the encoding is the problem.

Comment: MySQL doesn't and probably never will support Bcrypt, or if it does, Bcrypt will likely be obsolete and we'll have moved on to something better. This is why doing hash validation within MySQL is the wrong place to do it. MySQL does not even support the type of SHA2-256 hashing that `sha256_crypt` does, as it looks like that does 80,000 rounds of it. MySQL does *one*.

Comment: You could emulate this with `SHA2(SHA2(SHA2(...)))` nested 80,000 times, but that seems preposterous and would probably be stupidly slow because MySQL is not meant for that.

Comment: hi @tadman when VerneMQ eventually supports bcrypt with MySQL it would be client-side (that is the VerneMQ broker would do the bcrypt verification).